# merge text in column A with text in column B, output into column C - excel

Tags: excel, merge

Im currently copying over all my tags from Google reader (soon to be no more) to Feedly, to do this i need to have a comma separated list of tags.

Ive managed to get the list of tags in to column A in an excel sheet.

Ive pasted `,` in column B, what i want to do is output `tag,` into column C.

I was trying to do it with `=A1+B1` but because they are both strings this dosnt work, any ideas how i should approach this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenating strings helps:

```
=A1 & B1
```

or

```
CONCATENATE(A,B)
```

Answer (score 2):

Or alternatively to keep your data clean:
=A1 & ", " & B1

Answer (score 0):

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,B1)
```

or

```
=A1&B1
```